# Show vectors are linearly independent.

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $T: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$, a linear operator such that $T^3(v)=0$
>   Prove that $x \in \mathbb{R}^3$ isn't a linear combination of $T(x), T^2(x)$, Assuming $T^2(x) \ne 0$.

I was guided to do the following:
Let
$$y = c_1\cdot T(y) + c_2 \cdot T^2(y)$$

Therefore, $$T^2(y)=c_1\cdot T^3(y) + c_2\cdot T^3(T(y)) = 0$$

I'm not sure how it comes in handy here though

Comment: Looks like you are being asked to do a proof by contradiction. Assume $y$ is a linear combination of $T(y), T^2(y)$ and show you get $T^2(y)=0$, which contradicts the assumption in the problem of $T^2(y) \neq 0$.

Comment: Your answer is right, just mention the method, here you proved the contraposition that is equivalent to the main proposition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose

$$x=aTx+bT^2x\;,\;\;a,b\in\Bbb R\implies Tx=aT^2x+\underbrace{bT^3x}_{=0}=aT^2x\implies$$

$$T^2x=aT^3x=0\;,\;\;\text{contradiction}$$

Comment: Oh nice. I feel so stupid right now.